# Chaining Asynchronous Functions Node.js bluebird mongoskin

Tags: javascript, node.js, asynchronous, promise, bluebird

I have been reading many posts on how to chain asynchronous functions but I just can't seem to get it right!

As the title indicates. I am trying to chain mongoskin database calls together, so that i can gather all the information in chunks and then finally send the accumulated result in the response.

I have the object user as :

```
var User = {
       username: 'someusername',
       accounts: [{name: 'account_1'}, {name: 'account_2'}]
   }
```

For each of the accounts I need to gather data and then send the accumulated data in the response. So i am using the following for loop to iterate over the accounts:

```
var promise = require('bluebird');
var db = require('mongoskin').db('mongodb://localhost/someDB');

for(var x in user.accounts){
   //Fetch account data
   user.accounts[x].accountData = fetchAccountData(user.accounts[x].name);
}

//Finally send the collected response
response.send(user);
```

And the function fetchAccountData looks like the following:

```
function fetchAccountData(screen_id){
   db.collection('master')
     .aggregate([
        {$match: {screen_id: screen_id}}
      ], function(err, res){
           if(err)
              return null;
           else{
              console.log('Done', screen_id);
              return res;
          }
     });
 }
```

How can i chain this to have the following algorithm:

```
 start:
      for each account:
           fetchDataForAccount
      Finally:
           Send Response
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your algorithm can be achieved using the following code:

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongo = require('mongoskin'), db;

Promise.promisifyAll(mongo.Collection.prototype);

db = mongo.db('mongodb://localhost/someDB');

Promise.all(user.accounts.map(function(acct) {
  return fetchAccountData(acct.name).then(function(data) {
    acct.accountData = data;
  });
}))
.then(function() {
  response.send(user);
})
.catch(function(err) {
  // handle error
});

function fetchAccountData(screen_id){
   return db
     .collection('master')
     .aggregateAsync([
        {$match: {screen_id: screen_id}}
      ]);
}
```

EDIT: Here's a breakdown of the code

The first thing you need to do is ensure that `aggregate` returns a *Promise* instead of using a continuation (e.g. callback). You can do this by using bluebird's amazing [promisification](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) abilities :) Here we use it on `mongo.Collection.prototype` so that when `collection()` is called it will return a promise-capable collection instance. Then we have `fetchAccountData` *return* the promise returned by `aggregateAsync` so the client has a way of knowing when that promise is resolved.

Next, we map over each account in accounts and return a promise which will be fulfilled once the account data is fetched *and* it has been assigned to the account object. We then use [Promise.all](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#all---promise) which will return a promise that is fulfilled "when all the items in the array are fulfilled" (from the docs).

Finally, we have to use `then()` to "wait" until the promise returned from all has resolved, and the finally send back the response with the complete user object.

Comment: Nice answer, a `Promise.map` would have been preferable to a `Promise.all` probably, could also use `.props` on the accounts but this is nice. +1

Comment: ahh Promise.map looks great! Even with Bluebird I tend to stick to the native API, but I should really explore it more.

Comment: Thanks alot. That worked wonderfully. I had a question, How would i format the query if i wanted to chain mongo functions for example, **db.collection('').find({}).count()** ? Thanks you

Comment: np! `db.collection('').findAsync({}).then(function() { return collection.countAsync(); })` Promises are always unwrapped and once you `promisifyAll` an object all of its methods get additional `methodAsync` names that represent the same methods, except they return a promise. The [bluebird docs](https://github.com/petkaantonov/bluebird/blob/master/API.md#promisification) have more info on this.